# Can't center react component on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a modal window, which opens on the click of the user. I am trying to center it and use standard CSS code:

```
.layout: {
    position: "absolute";
    left: "50%";
    top: "50%";
}
```

But it centers element inside its parent, and I don't know why, because a parent has static position (so absolute should count from the edge of the screen, not a parent). How to fix it? 
Here is the structure of a modal window:

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="window">
        <!--some code --!>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  you want to center it on whole screen then position fixed will be the choice for you, and don't use hardcoded  pixels to center it, istead use Transform property, Like this

```
.layout {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

and if you want to center it in some section or div, then use position absolute,

```
.layout {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

But in absolute condition, give `position: relative` to its parent.

if you will use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` you will never need to worry about the height or width of your item, in hardcoded pixels, if your element's height and width will increase or decrease, then your alignment of the item will distort.

check the example below with position fixed,

```css
.layout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
    <div class="window">
        <!--some code --!>
        ABC
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if this will help you, then dont forget to mark this as right answer

Answer (score 1):

In this case, if you use absolute or fixed positioning, you need to set negative margins of half width and height of your element you need to center. if you want to set you element related the whole screen it better use position 'fixed'

```css
.element {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
```

if you need more flexible solution, when you don't know popup's size, use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` instead of margins.

but better solution will be use flexboxes trhttps://alligator.io/css/centering-using-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

The CSS `position: absolute` attribute positions it relative to the nearest positioned parent node. If you want to position your element relative to the viewport, you should use `position: fixed`.

You can find more info about the options for this property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).